# Connect mobile devices (iOS & Android) to VNC Server with QT / C++ and mirror display

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, vnc

I've a problem, I'm not an expert of VNC but, i've installed http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/ on rasperry, and connect him to display.

Now, I'get the display mirroring thought vnc, but I didn't found documents about connect to VNC Server.
My target is write code from QT Cross Platform, connect on VNC server on rasperry and start mirroring on client devices (tablet or smartphone - iOS & Android).
Exist the documentations to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here, Check this out:

http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/09/23/full-featured-vnc-client-widget-for-qt/

This guy programmed a custom view for VNC clients in Qt. Looks like that's what you need; if not, please be more specific.

Comment: I've tryed, the client connect on tcp, but don't send video frames. it's not cross tool.